# What time do the daily quests reset?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

What time do daily quests reset?  Is it the same time per server (going by server time), per region, or is it a timer per person?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[I am told](http://www.ownedcore.com/forums/star-wars-old-republic/swtor-guides/338561-swtor-daily-guide-lvl-50-imperial.html): **7 AM EST** (with weeklies resetting Tuesday).

Further more, it is my understanding [this is universal](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=57222) (**6 AM CST, 1 PM CET**).

Comment: that's 12:00 UTC, not a weird time at all.

Answer (score 0):

Tested today for you:

7AM server time on Space Slug.

US West Coast server.

Hope this helps.